# jQuery: Multiple audio player buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I would like to make 4 play buttons which plays mp3 audio. The play function is working every 4 buttons, but unfortunately the pause is not working for either of them. Maybe the pause condition is wrong?

```htm
<div class="audio-button">
    <audio src="media/test.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="audio-button">
    <audio src="media/test2.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="audio-button">
    <audio src="media/test3.mp3"></audio>
</div>
<div class="audio-button">
    <audio src="media/test4.mp3"></audio>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var playing = false;

    $('.audio-button').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("playing");
        var song = $(this).find('audio').attr('src');
        var audio = new Audio(song);

        if (playing == false) {
            audio.play();
            playing = true;
        } else {
            audio.pause();
            playing = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you "clone" the audio (by `var audio = new Audio(song);`)? Try  `$(this).find('audio')[0].pause()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to grab the audio element directly from the button as a child and interact with that. You do not need to clone the `Audio` object using a constructor.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var playing = false;

  // Add file names.
  $('.audio-button').each(function() {
    var $button = $(this);    
    var $audio = $button.find('audio');
    
    $($('<span>').text($audio.attr('src'))).insertBefore($audio);
  });

  // Add click listener.
  $('.audio-button').click(function() {
    var $button = $(this);    
    var audio = $button.find('audio')[0]; // <-- Interact with this!
    
    // Toggle play/pause
    if (playing !== true) {
      audio.play();
    } else {
      audio.pause();
    }

    // Flip state
    $button.toggleClass('playing');
    playing = !playing
  });
});
```

```css
.fa.audio-button {
  position:      relative;
  display:       block;
  width:         12em;
  height:        2.25em;
  margin-bottom: 0.125em;
  text-align:    left;
}

.fa.audio-button:after {
  position:      absolute;
  right:         0.8em;
  content:       "\f04b";
}

.fa.audio-button.playing:after {
  content:       "\f04c";
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="fa audio-button">
  <audio src="media/test.mp3"></audio>
</button>
<button class="fa audio-button">
  <audio src="media/test2.mp3"></audio>
</button>
<button class="fa audio-button">
  <audio src="media/test3.mp3"></audio>
</button>
<button class="fa audio-button">
  <audio src="media/test4.mp3"></audio>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

do you want to stop the other three when one is clicked?

If so you can try:

`$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.audio-button').click(function (e) {
        var button = $(e.target).closest('.audio-button');
        var audio = button.find('audio');
        var audioDom = audio.get(0);
        $('audio[data-is-playing]').not(audio).each(function (i, currentAudioDom) {
            var currentButton = $(currentAudioDom).closest('.audio-button');
            currentButton.removeClass('playing');
            currentButton.removeAttr('data-is-playing');
            currentAudioDom.$audio.pause();
        });
        button.addClass('playing');
        audio.attr('data-is-playing', '');
        audioDom.$audio = audioDom.$audio || new Audio(audio.attr('src'));
        audioDom.$audio.play();
    });
});`

Fix:

Actually I'm not sure if the audio element is an Audio Object in itself, if so, you can call the play/pause directly on the audioDom/currentAudioDom elements and forget about the $audio thing...