# play a track using font awesome icon

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome, mp3

Is it possible to play a song using a font awesome icon, for example on the left will be the song name(mp3) and just to right of the track name will be a play font awesome icon, is it possible for a user to click on the play icon and the track starts playing and they can pause it and stop it

There will be about 10 tracks in the list

Has anyone got a sample code or a link to something similar please? I am guessing it will need some sort of javascript for the icons to be able to play, pause and stop

I found this code: http://jsfiddle.net/7341jxv6/2/ but am trying to amend it to use the font awesome play and pause icons instead of the text play and pause

My updated code is below

```
 <audio id="audio1" src="tracks/ub40-ska/kingston-town.mp3"></audio>
 <audio id="audio2" src="tracks/ub40-ska/homely-girl.mp3"></audio>
 <audio id="audio3" src="tracks/ub40-ska/red-red-wine.mp3"></audio>
 <audio id="audio4" src="tracks/ub40-ska/one-in-ten.mp3"></audio>

 <div class="play" id="btn1"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
 <div class="play" id="btn2"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
 <div class="play" id="btn3"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
 <div class="play" id="btn4"><i class="fa fa-play-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>

 <script>
 $('.play').click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
var id = $this.attr('id').replace(/btn/, '');
$this.toggleClass('active');
if($this.hasClass('active')){
    $this.addClass('fa-pause-circle');  
    $('audio[id^="audio"]')[id-1].play();        
} else {
    $this.removeClass('fa-play-circle');
    $('audio[id^="audio"]')[id-1].pause();
}
});
</script>
```

If I click on the play icon, it does play but the icon then disappears but if I click in the same place, it does pause the music

Comment: You can add the icon to a button

Answer (score 0):

You can write click listener for the fa-icon;

**DOM looks like this**

`<div class="play-tab">
    <div class="track-name">Some Track Name<div>
    <span class="icons"><i class="fa fa-play"/><span>
<div>"`

**JQuery**

```
$(".play-tab").on("click" , "i", function(e){//fetch song id and play})
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use the same button then you need a function that will change the icon and stop/play music

```js
var myAudio = document.getElementById('media_audio');
var icon = document.getElementById('toglePlayPause');
var togglePlayPauseButton = document.getElementById('media_controls_play-pause-button');
//Event listener for the play button
togglePlayPauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
       if ( myAudio.paused ||  myAudio.ended) {
          if ( myAudio ) {
              myAudio.title = 'Play';
              icon.className = "fa fa-play";
          }
          myAudio.play();
      } else {
          if ( myAudio ) {
              myAudio.title = 'Pause';
              icon.className = "fa fa-pause";
          }
          myAudio.pause();
      }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="media_player">
        <audio id="media_audio" >
                Your browser does not support the audio tag.
        </audio>
        <div id='media_controls' >
            <button 
              id="media_controls_play-pause-button"
              class='icon'          
              title="Pause">
              <i id="toglePlayPause" class="fa fa-pause"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you Edhar, I have used this coding and it works for one track but if I add a second track, it does not play, am I right in saying the audio id needs to be different for each track?

Comment: Hello. It's good that I can help you. You need only one audio tag and for every new track, you can change the source tag "src" attribute. Here fast I find some examples 

http://devblog.lastrose.com/html5-audio-video-playlist/  or this one

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106933/html5-javascript-audio-playlist

Comment: Thank you, I went with new coding I found but unsure how to swap the play icon to a pause icon. I have edited my original post with the new coding I am using

Comment: You can use the logic from the function that I post before. It was tested and work correctly. If it's helpful here is my repo with other functions for a video player https://github.com/edgardovbak/video_player but the logic is the same for audio.

Comment: Sorry am not good at javascript and not sure how to integrate the function from your code into the new code, can't work out how to do it sorry

Comment: I have updated the code above as getting bit closer but got the issue of the icon disappearing after clicking play

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code above as getting bit closer but got the issue of the icon disappearing after clicking play

Answer (score 0):

You try to change icon on button element but the icon is on "i" tag.
To fix the bug you need to add a small fixes to your code

```
$('.play').click(function(){
var $this = $(this);
var id = $this.attr('id').replace(/btn/, '');
$this.toggleClass('active');
if($this.hasClass('active')){
    $this.find("i").removeClass('fa-play-circle');
    $this.find("i").addClass('fa-pause-circle');  
    $('audio[id^="audio"]')[id-1].play();        
} else {
    $this.find("i").removeClass('fa-pause-circle');
    $this.find("i").addClass('fa-play-circle');  
    $('audio[id^="audio"]')[id-1].pause();
}
});
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your code and they still disappear and noticed they end up way down the page, wonder if it's conflicting with some other javascript or something. It does pause the music if click in the same place, just the icons disappear to way down the page

Comment: Try to add your code to a code snippet, it will be helpful, and much more ease to help you.

Comment: I created a pastebin with the code, hopefully it helps - https://pastebin.com/9fQfXKYr

Comment: I have managed to find what I am looking for and works fine at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37836002/jquery-multiple-audio-player-buttons, it would be good say if I clicked on one, it plays but if click on another it stops the current one playing and plays the other one I clicked on

There was a fix for that in that link but it don't seem to work